# Access Database: Script that works when manually run is failing in MS Task Scheduler

Tags: python, ms-access, automation, scheduled-tasks

**Problem**

I have a Python script that exports a report from an Access Database to a PDF file. The script itself works fine when run manually, however when that same exact script is added to Task Scheduler (either via Python file or batch file), the script fails due to the following error:

> (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "Contact Management
> Database can't save the output data to the file you've selected.",
> None, -1, -2146825986), None)

I don't understand why I can run the script manually and have it work as expected, but when running via Task Scheduler, it gives me that error.

**Script**

```
import win32com.client
from pathlib import Path
from UtilityBelt import write

access_db_path = Path(r'<Access Database Path>')

report_name = r'<Name of Report in Access>'

report_output = Path(r'<Export folder>\test.pdf')

if report_output.exists():
    # Deletes existing report if applicable
    report_output.unlink()

try:
    a = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Access.Application")

    # Open the database
    db = a.OpenCurrentDatabase(access_db_path)

    # Exports the selected report to a PDF
    a.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, report_name, r'PDF Format (*.pdf)', str(report_output))

    a.Application.Quit()

except Exception as e:
    write(logfile, str(e))
```

**Relevant Task Scheduler Settings**

***General***

Run whether user is logged in or not

Run with highest privileges

***Actions***

Program/script

- <path to folder>\access_testing.bat

Start in (optional)

- <path to folder>

**Batch File**

`@echo off`

`"<path to python folder>\python.exe" "<path to folder>\access_testing.py"`

`pause`

I've tried creating a brand new test access database, logging out then back in, restarting the computer, running in Task Scheduler via Python and Batch, playing with the action parameters, exporting to a local drive as opposed to a network drive, exporting a different file type, running with a different user, ... No luck with anything I've tried.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use absolute paths everywhere? If not, you should change that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Absolute paths are used in this script as they will all be run on a dedicated computer and are not required to be run on other machines.

Comment: If UNC pathing doesn't correct, likely issue is not with code but with computer/network setup. Have you talked to your IT support?

Comment: Unfortunately the error is persisting despite all paths being set to UNC paths :(

I haven't yet talked to IT support, but I do have a meeting with them next week and I'll bring it up then. This script was working in the past for a different user, but I have since taken over. Only thing I can think of is a permissions issue, but I don't understand why I can manually run the exact same script yet have it fail in Task Scheduler. In any case, thank you for the reply!

Comment: Cross post https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=87356

Comment: _I can think of is a permissions issue .._ Yes, that's what it is. Check the account that the Task Sceduler is using.

Answer (score 0):

**2023-01-20 UPDATE**

Turns out it wasn't an issue with permissions, Access, Python, or anything like that. It was an issue with Task Scheduler as I thought, but it turned out to be a much simpler fix than I thought it would be.

The option of "Run whether a user is logged in or not" was causing the issue. Changing this to "Run only when a user is logged in" fixed the problem.

This task was running on a dedicated desktop that I would remote into. Despite never logging out when ending a session (just closing the Remote Desktop window), setting the task to "Run only when a user is logged in" fixed the task.

As the script opens Access and exports a PDF from there - a process that requires a user being logged in - my best guess is that having the option to run whether logged in or not, conflicted with that process and caused the export to fail. Glad that one is solved. Sometimes the fix is a simple one!